# Evalutating the following integral: $\int\frac{\ln(x) dx}{x+4x\ln^2(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to find this integral but I work on it an hour now still no clue... please just give me a HINT and not the answer so that I can find it on my own and learn via this process. Here is the integral:!

### $$\int\frac{\ln(x) dx}{x+4x\ln^2(x)}$$

It is so difficult!!!

Comment: Note $x+4x\ln^2 x=x(1+4\ln^2 x)$.

Comment: okay wait wait wait ......

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

With a change of variable (find it) the integral becomes:
$$\int\frac{u}{1+4u^2}du$$